# Show "Menu" in Bootstrap 3 mobile screen instead of three lines (<em>)?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to change the Bootstrap 3 menu ...

[image]

... so it reads like "Menu" instead og the three lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this:

```
 <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        Menu
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
```

instead of this

```
   <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
```

check this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/244e8c1b/2/

Comment: Will this alternate between the 3 lines on a cell phone screen & a traditional menu when on a computer?